# Matrix with gradient ranging from certain value to zero

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create a matrix which has in its "lower left" corner it's maximum value (e.g. 10) and in the "lower right" and "upper left" corner 0 as its value. The matrix should be filled with values ranging from the maximum value to one and then with zeros.

```
##e.g. start with this
m <- matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
m[,1] <- 1:10
m[10, ] <- 10:1
```

What is the most efficient way to fill the matrix analogously to

```
## 1 0 0 0
## 2 1 0 0 
## 3 2 1 0
## 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Can you please show the expected output? You don't need a 10*10 matrix for that, 4*4 should be sufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I understood, this could be done for example like this:

```
n <- 4
sapply((n:1)-1, "+", 1:n)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    4    3    2    1
# [2,]    5    4    3    2
# [3,]    6    5    4    3
# [4,]    7    6    5    4
```

It can also be seen as a part of a Toeplitz matrix, see `?toeplitz`.

---

I misunderstood the explanations! The example helped a lot.
In order to match the example, there are many possible solutions.

#### Solution 1 with `toeplitz`

```
n <- 4
M <- toeplitz(1:n)
M[upper.tri(M)] <- 0
M

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    2    1    0    0
# [3,]    3    2    1    0
# [4,]    4    3    2    1
```

#### Solution 2 with `sapply` and `pmax`

```
sapply((1:n)-1, function(i)  pmax((1:n)-i, 0) )

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    2    1    0    0
# [3,]    3    2    1    0
# [4,]    4    3    2    1
```

NB: with a little tweak, `pmax` can be placed outside the `sapply`, as in `pmax(-sapply((1:n)-1, "-", 1:n),0)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
m[lower.tri(m, diag = T)] <- sequence(10:1)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
lower.tri(m, diag=T) %*% lower.tri(m, diag=T)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [2,]    2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [3,]    3    2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [4,]    4    3    2    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [5,]    5    4    3    2    1    0    0    0    0     0
# [6,]    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    0    0     0
# [7,]    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    0     0
# [8,]    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0     0
# [9,]    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1     0
#[10,]   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2     1
```